# How to select the first 10 records for each table in the same database using sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 50+ tables in a database.

I don't want to use the following SQL on each table in a database.

```
select * from {table_name}
```

So, is it possible to display the first 10 records for each table inside the same database using sql?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd be careful about using `sp_MSforeachtable`, as it uses the same code pattern as `sp_MSforeachdb`. I've pointed out the problems with `sp_MSforeachdb` [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/) (work backward) and was told it wouldn't be fixed on Connect (before they killed it, and so this link no longer works) [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/264677/sp-msforeachdb-provide-supported-documented-version).

Instead I would do something like this (which also includes the table name in the output, probably useful):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'

SELECT TOP (10) [table] = N''' + REPLACE(name, '''','') + ''', * 
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]))
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.tables AS t;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

When you're satisfied with the `PRINT` output (note that it will truncate at 8K), uncomment the `EXEC`.

Comment: This works well. What is the best way to export all of the results as one file? For example, I have 15 tables, so I now have 15 sets of data that were returned.

Comment: @systech Well, do you have 15 tables with the same structure? If so, you could build a UNION ALL. If not, then you could use an app to do it, or concatenate everything into a big ugly string, but what would you be doing with a file that had data from 15 different tables in it?

Comment: I have inherited a database that has 15 tables, and I would like to see the first 10 or so rows of each table. The above code helps with that, but I would like to export them all to one document or file, in order to get an idea of what each table contains.

Comment: thanks, I stole from your answer to make my question : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194859/how-to-trun-a-query-result-to-text-to-be-executed-as-storedprocedure

Answer (score 6):

Use sp_MSforeachtable

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'select top(10) * from ?'
```

To show the table Name you should change it like this :

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'select "?" as table_Name , * from ?'
```

Comment: How do I let it shows the name of the table that the records is showing

Comment: @Jack I updated my answer, the second query retrieves table names too.

Comment: I'd be careful about using undocumented, unsupported procedures like this. [I have pointed out serious problems with `sp_MSforeachdb`](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb), which will never be fixed, and I believe it is possible for the same symptoms to appear in `sp_MSforeachtable` under slightly different circumstances.

Comment: @MaryamArshi, Sorry to untick your solution because Aaron Solution is much better but I have upvote you.

Comment: @Jack The main idea of being here is to learn and teach best solutions, so I am always happy to know there is a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 3):

sp_MSforeachtable is great. but if you want to somehow limit which tables to look at (for example, just 'dbo' schema) you can generate select scripts like this:

```
select 'Select Top 10 * From ' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name 
from sys.objects 
where type = 'U' -- and SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)  = 'dbo'
```

Comment: Why not `sys.tables` which doesn't need the `type` filter?

Comment: @AaronBertrand if you like so..