# Creating bacpac failed (DoAllowRowLocks / DoAllowPageLocks)

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm creating a bacpac file from a local database for import to Azure SQL Server, but I keep getting an error which I cannot seem to resolve.

```
Error SQL71564: Element Primary Key has an unsupported property DoAllowRowLocks set and is not supported
    when used as part of a data package. 
Error SQL71564: Element Primary Key has an unsupported property DoAllowPageLocks set and is not supported
    when used as part of a data package.
```

And this error repeats itself for 50 more keys. I have been focussing on this problem for 2 days fulltime now, and I would really like some help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problems using these script:

[Rebuild all indexes]

```
USE AdventureWorks;
declare @table_name varchar(200)
declare @SQL varchar(300)

DECLARE vendor_cursor cursor 
        FOR SELECT sys.tables.name
        FROM sys.tables WHERE sys.tables.name NOT LIKE '%_dss'
OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor 
INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SELECT @SQL =  'ALTER INDEX ALL ON '+@table_name+' REBUILD';
 EXEC(@SQL);
 print 'INDEX Rebuild on all indexes in table '+@table_name+' is done.';
 FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor  INTO @table_name
END 
CLOSE vendor_cursor;
DEALLOCATE vendor_cursor;
GO
```

I also needed to change the IsNotForReplication property.
This script turns it YES for all tables that have an identity column.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1 = '
declare @int int
set @int =object_id("?")
EXEC sys.sp_identitycolumnforreplication @int, 1'
```

This script turns it NO for all tables that have an identity column.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1 = ‘
declare @int int
set @int =object_id(“?”)
EXEC sys.sp_identitycolumnforreplication @int, 0′
```

Comment: Be careful with using undocumented SP. Aaron has pointed out [**here**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35615/8783) and has showed how you can use dynamic sql as an alternative.